# calling an array index with a variable

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, list

I am trying to test a specific element from a list, and compare it to a string the user inputs. It is inside an if statement:
    `if (textboxinput.Text.ToString() == main.steps[current])`
In this context, current is an integer equal to 0, and after the if statement is done current++.
 this is a new wpf form window that is opened by clicking a button on the MainWindow wpf form. main is instantiated from the MainWindow1 class containing our list: 
`public List<string> steps = new List<string>();` 
 Whenever I run this code, I receive the argument out of range exception.

In short: I am trying substitute the index of the list with a variable, and it is saying it is out of range.
Still learning c#, and this is probably an easy fix, and it's probably a super obvious rule I'm forgetting, but any help would be appreciated, as the same exception happens on arrays as well.
      Here is the event for the button being clicked

```
int current = 0;
private void buttonanswer_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (textboxinput.Text.ToString() == main.steps[current])
        {
            textboxoutput.Foreground = Brushes.Green;
            textboxoutput.AppendText(textboxinput + Environment.NewLine);
            textboxinput.Clear();


        }
        else
        {
            textboxoutput.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
            textboxoutput.AppendText(textboxinput + Environment.NewLine);
            textboxinput.Clear();
        }
        current++;
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you instantiate the main.steps array?

Comment: ' MainWindow main = new MainWindow();' Is this what you were looking for? I just used main.steps to call from that

Comment: Unless you were referring to this? ` public List <string> steps = new List<string>(); `

Comment: `public List <string> steps = new List<string>();` means `main.steps` contains zero elements, so `main.steps[current]` is out of range. You have to populate `main.steps` first.

Comment: Thank you for the answer that seemed to be the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that when you're looping current, it is always less than the length of the main.steps array. Remember, if an array contains 5 elements, they are numbered 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4 for example. Most likely you are allowing current to reach the number 5 (or whatever is the size of your array in your particular case). This type of mistake would be what causes an out of bounds exception when working with an array.

Comment: current is initially set to 0 at the beginning of the program, then at the end of the button_click event it is increased by 1. The exception occurs the first time I check this, so the value of current is = 0. The list.add function was used to add strings the user inputted to the list. I thought that lists were different from arrays in that they could be added on to, and their size automatically grows.

Comment: Are you printing out current? Print statements are always the key to debugging. Make absolutely sure that the value of current is 0 at the time of the crash. Posting more of the code as well might make it easier to get to the bottom of your problem.

Comment: I added the button clicked event code, and I will have it print out in the meantime.

Comment: I debugged an I outputted the number of elements in the array, which updated normally and after entering 4 inputs, it was 4. The current was 0 at the time of the error.

Comment: If right before you do that the number of elements is 4 and current is definitely 0, then I have to say I am out of guesses. Problem with it is probably located elsewhere if I had to guess.

Comment: Ok well I'd imagine I'm using the incorrect way to test the array it's self, but thank you for your help either way.